# Lemoon - Creating a new content Type causing errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-type, lemoon

I have created a new 'Jobs' Content type. Basically I want this to work in the same fashion as Modules, they will simply allow job listings to be posted on a Careers page.  I have it mostly working, the content type shows up in the admin and I can enter data as I want. However I cannot get it to render on the page now - I keep receiving errors when I try to loop through and print out the Jobs.

In my JobsTemplate.aspx file I have the following:

```
<% if (!Content.Jobs.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
                foreach (var item in Content.Jobs.AsSmartEnumerable()) {
                    var job = item.Value.Value as Jobs; %>

                    <% if (item.Index % 3 == 0) { %>
                    <div class="row-fluid modules">
                    <% } %>

                    <div class="span4">
                    <h2><%: job.Title %></h2>
                    <%= job.Body %>
                    <% if (job.Link.HasValue()) { %><p><a class="btn" href="<%= job.Link.Url() %>"><%: Resources.Strings.LearnMore %> &raquo;</a></p>
                    <% } %>
                    </div>

                    <% if (item.IsLast || !item.IsFirst && item.Index % 2 == 0) { %>
                    </div>
                    <% } %>

                <% } %>

                <% }%>
```

And this yields the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Mindroute.Lemoon.Modules.CoreModule.Page' does not contain a definition for 'Jobs' and no extension method 'Jobs' accepting a first argument of type 'Mindroute.Lemoon.Modules.CoreModule.Page' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am I missing?  On the JobsTemplate.aspx file I am using the JobsTemplate as the codebehind and inherits values - is this where I am screwing up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JobTemplates.aspx page is used to render a page of content type Mindroute.Lemoon.Modules.CoreModule.Page and the compiler tells you that the Page content type does not have a Jobs property.

What you should do is create a content type called Careers (or modify an existing) and add a property definition like:

```
public List<ContentRef> Jobs { get; set; }
```

You must then tell your Template that it should render a content item of type Careers like:

```
public partial class CareersTemplate : PageBase<Careers>
```

and finally you need to edit the Careers content type in admin to use the CareersTemplate.

Comment: Ok I abandoned what I was trying to do and just tried to create a new Content Type in the Admin. However each time I try, even if its just a single input I get server errors. Here is a screenshot of the error: [link](http://d.pr/i/G8Q2) I have tried using several different Page Templates - but always chokes on the Content.Title :/

Comment: I should note that it saves the info just fine and all seems to be well in the admin side - just client side it pukes.

Comment: Looks like Content is null. This can happen if the code behind of your Template inherits from the "wrong" type. Templates are generic and should normally inherit from PageBase<YourContentTypeHere>. See http://www.lemoon.com/developers/programming/aspnet/templates

Comment: Yeah, however no matter which template I choose I get this error - I haven't modified any of them at this point, I deleted the JobsTemplate I originally created in an attempt to get job listings in the mix.  But now when I just try to create a new Content Type in the admin I keep getting this error on the front end, like I said - everything is working great in the admin as expected.

Comment: You normally can't select any template to render a page. Templates and Content types are tightly coupled so if you create a new content type you will also need to create a template for rendering that content type.

Comment: Ah, ok - so what then exactly needs to happen if i want to create a new template and its counterpart content type?  No matter what I try I keep getting the **NullReferenceException** errors. :{  Let just say even if I create a new content type called 'Jobs' in the admin with a single textblock named 'currentOpening'... what needs to exist in the Template in order for that to work?  I feel like I need you on retainer lajjne ;)